# Modifying string value

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which is

```
string a = @"\server\MainDirectory\SubDirectoryA\SubDirectoryB\SubdirectoryC\MyFile.pdf";
```

The **SubDirectoryB** will always start with a prefix of **RN** followed by 6 unique numbers. Now I'm trying to modify `SubDirectoryB` parth of the string to be replaced by a new value lets say **RN012345**

So the new string should look like

```
string b = @"\server\MainDirectory\SubDirectoryA\RN012345\SubdirectoryC\MyFile.pdf";
```

To achieve this I'm making use of the following helper method

```
public static string ReplaceAt(this string path, int index, int length, string replace)
{
   return path.Remove(index, Math.Min(length, path.Length - index)).Insert(index, replace);
}
```

Which works great for now.

However the orginial path will be changing in the near future so it will something like `@\MainDirectory\RN012345\AnotherDirectory\MyFile.pdf`. So I was wondering if there is like a `regex` or another feature I can use to just change the value in the path rather than providing the index which will change in the future.

Comment: What is the value in the input string you want to replace by `RN012345`? Is it a position in the path (i.e. 2nd sub-directory)?

Comment: There has to be some clear and consistent rule. Relying on 'RN' is going to cause you trouble - what if there's more than one subfolder in the path with 'RN'?. Is there always the same of sub-folders? Or will you know the value of SubDirectoryA at runtime?

Comment: didnt you ask almost this yesterday? I remember seeing that exact pathing...

Comment: @BugFinder it's similar but this is replacing the path and that was getting the path

Comment: @Zesty yes I will know the value of `SubDirectoryA` at runtime

Comment: @Niitaku I want to replace `SubDirectoryB` with the value `RN012345`

Comment: So, for example, you want to replace a `RN987654` folder name in input string by `RN012345`. Is that it?

Comment: @Niitaku Yes that's correct

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"\\RN\d{6}\\", "\\RN012345\\")`. `\d{6}` will match any 6 digits, not checking if they are unique. Do you need that kind of check?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes please, if it's not too much hassle

Comment: It is easy to check within a match evaluator inside `Regex.Replace` *replacement* argument. It can be done with a pure regex, but the pattern will become "scary". In your current code, you do not actually check if the digits are unique. Do you really need that kind of a check?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Would it be possible if you can provide an answer please

Comment: Check http://ideone.com/ehI5Hn - does it do what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to only replace those `\RNxxxxxx\` where each `x` is a unique digit, you need to capture the 6 digits and analyze the substring inside  a match evaluator.

```
var a = @"\server\MainDirectory\SubDirectoryA\RN012345\SubdirectoryC\MyFile.pdf";
var res = Regex.Replace(a, @"\\RN([0-9]{6})\\", m =>
        m.Groups[1].Value.Distinct().Count() == m.Groups[1].Value.Length ?
          "\\RN0123456\\" : m.Value);
// res => \server\MainDirectory\SubDirectoryA\RN0123456\SubdirectoryC\MyFile.pdf
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/ehI5Hn)

The regex is

```
\\RN([0-9]{6})\\
```

It matches a `\` with `\\`, then matches `RN`, then matches and captures into Group 1 six digits (with `([0-9]{6})`) and then will match a `\`. In the replacment part, the `m.Groups[1].Value.Distinct().Count() == m.Groups[1].Value.Length` checks if the number of distinct digits is the same as the number of the substring captured, and if yes, the digits are unique and the replacement occurs, else, the whole match is put back into the replacement result.

Comment: Thank you for this, so if I didn't want to take into account the distinct digist I can remove `m.Groups[1].Value.Distinct().Count() == m.Groups[1].Value.Length`?

Comment: Then all you need is `Regex.Replace(a, @"\\RN[0-9]{6}\\", "\\" + your_value + "\\")`

Comment: Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string oldSubdirectoryB = "RN012345";
string newSubdirectoryB = "RN147258";

string fileNameWithPath = @"\server\MainDirectory\SubDirectoryA\RN012345\SubdirectoryC\MyFile.pdf";

fileNameWithPath = fileNameWithPath.Replace(oldSubdirectoryB, newSubdirectoryB);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the `SubDirectoryB` name was used in question to simiplify things. The Directory will always begin with `RN` followed by 6 unique numbers so this might not work

Comment: Does the application know the 6 unique numbers at runtime?

Comment: Yes it will be in in the path. So for example the entire string will contain the path and the `SubDirectoryB` will be `RN012345` I want to replace that `RN012345` with `RN147258`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the difficulty. So, can't you use myPath.Replace("RN012345", "RN147258"); Aren't both values known at runtime?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Regex.Replace` to replace the `SubDirectoryB` with your required value

```
string a = @"\server\MainDirectory\SubDirectoryA\RN123456\SubdirectoryC\MyFile.pdf";
a = Regex.Replace(a, "RN[0-9]{6,6}","Mairaj");
```

Here i have replaced a `string` with `RN` followed by `6 numbers` with `Mairaj`.